# Enlarging the continuum with $\sigma$-centered forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

How large can we force the continuum to be if we force with a $\sigma$-centered forcing notion?

References to texts discussing the subject would be much appreciated.

[A forcing notion $P$ is called $\sigma$-centered if it can be written as $\bigcup _{n<\omega}P_n$ where for each $n$, every finite subset of $P_n$ has a lower bound in $P$.]

Comment: Let $\kappa = 2^{\aleph_0}$. For $\tau \in V^P \cap 2^{\omega}$, define $A_{\tau} = \{ (n, k, i) : n, k < \omega, i < 2, (\exists p \in P_n)(p \Vdash \tau(k) = i) \}$. If $p$ forces $\tau \neq \sigma$, then $A_{\tau} \neq A_{\sigma}$. So $V^{P} \models 2^{\aleph_0} = \kappa$.